# Debug="false" breaks bundling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundle, web-deployment

Over the weekend we have deployed a new version of an MVC web application to a Windows Server hosted in IIS 6. All of the CSS and Jquery files are configured to use bundling, on first deployment none of the bundles pulled through correctly. Short bit of Google research later and it appears setting debug="true" in the web.config fixes the issue.

I am not comfortable leaving a production web app running in debug mode, does anybody have another fix or any insight into exactly why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine has actually found a fix, there was an Exception in a Helper method that is not system critical. This caused the bundling to completely stop working, even though the method in question did not actually affect the bundle config.

Strange one, but thanks for responses

Answer (score 0):

debug="true" will disable your bundling. there is some problem in your bundling. that's why the bundling was not working at the release and only working in the debug mode. Can you post you bundling configuration section ?

Comment: A colleague has actually found a fix, which is quite an interesting one.